# Retrieve MAX value of a column mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a mysql table with a column name packageId being run through NodeJs. I am trying to retrieve the highest instance of that row. For example, if the column has 2,3,4,5, it should only retrieve 5.

I have tried to use the mysql function MAX into query, but the query doesnt seem to run. If i remove the MAX function, it runs and just consoles out each column value. I only want to return a single value, the highest.

```
connectionSelectPackageId.connect();

let sqlSelectPackageId = "SELECT MAX(packageId) FROM recipients";

connectionSelectPackageId.query(sqlSelectPackageId, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(rows);
        console.log(rows[i]);
        console.log("package id" + rows[i].packageId);
    };
});
```

Comment: You need an alias name for your max() like this `SELECT MAX(packageId) as maxId FROM recipients`. Then try `rows[i].maxId`

Comment: where are you getting the iterator variable `i` from? I don't see it declared anywhere.

Comment: thanks the alias name did the trick, although I wonder why it's needed. If i wanted to store that value to use it in other parts of the code. Could i do               return var packageId = rows[i].maxId;?

Answer (score 1):

If Max() does not work try this:

```
SELECT packageId 
FROM recipients 
order by packageId desc 
limit 1
```

Comment: Thank you i got it to work by assigning an alias name with the max(). How would i be able to store the value as a variable so i can use that variable outside of query, and in other parts of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an alias in your query:

```
let sqlSelectPackageId = "SELECT MAX(packageId) as maxID FROM recipients";
```

Then you can access the max ID you're looking for by using the alias maxID.

```
    var test = rows[0].maxID;
    console.log(test);
```

This will then print out your maxID that was returned as just the number. So if your table has 1,2,3,4,5 as the packageId's in it, this query will return just 5 as rows[0].maxID.

I'm doing a similar thing, this is my code if it helps (using Node.js/express):

```
     mysql.pool.query('SELECT MAX (orderID) as maxID FROM Orders', function (error, tempResults, fields) {
    if (error) {
      res.write(JSON.stringify(error));
      res.end();
    }
    var test = tempResults[0].maxID;
    console.log(test);
    //do more stuff below...
```